# Visual Studio for Mac System.Windows.Input reference

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

I am trying to detect what key is pressed by a user, normally I can use the 'System.Windows.Input' reference, however when I try to reference it, there is no library for it.

[image]

Is there something that I am missing or is this just not supported on the Mac version of Visual Studio?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a big part of `System.Windows.Input` namespace is located in the `WindowsBase`.
But it won't help much, since `Keyboard` class that you're looking for is inside the `PresentationCore` assembly, which is a part of WPF, that isn't (and, I guess, never will be) supported on Mono.
The only viable (-ish) way to get [it](https://github.com/mono/olive/blob/master/class/PresentationCore/System.Windows.Input/Keyboard.cs) is to build from the sources a [part](https://github.com/mono/olive) of Mono that's never made it to release.

You can use `System.Windows.Forms`, though.

Comment: So I'm pretty sure using this will work, however I am trying to get the key information when the user presses one but I am not sure how to do so, any ideas? (http://imgur.com/a/QoBhz)

Answer (score 3):

You're right that is not possible (and isn't even logical to be possible).

Visual Studio for Mac is not for developing software for Windows at all and nearly nothing in namespace 'Windows' is available. As I said it shouldn't be even expected - for example in your case keyboards for Windows and Mac are just not 100% same, so even some key enumerations would be purely impossible to port.

Depending on the project type that you use (Mac app, iOS app, Android app, Xamarin forms app) you must find alternative APIs.

No one has ever made one user interface kit to work on another. They are just different. There can be only meta interface like Xamarin forms that brings only common things available everywhere so that they can be translated into every native user interface.

Comment: I'm surprised that when developing Visual Studio for Mac they didn't make a library that supports key input, that seems slightly strange don't you think?

Comment: They did, actually, more than one. The only kind one that is missing is WPF-related (and you can't use WPF anywhere except Windows anyway). For any desktop GUI application you can use either `System.Windows.Forms` or `Gtk#` (http://imgur.com/a/1jIOO) to get the same functionality.

Comment: @AlexMarchant All operating systems have native API for key input. However, on Mac you are supposed to use Xamarin.Mac to call macOS API to build UI, and do whatever you should. It is not strange, just another set of framework for you to learn and master.

Comment: @Lemx pointing people to Mono's WinForms or GTK# is not currently a good suggestion. The former is incomplete, and the latter is more for Linux. Of course, they should work in some way.

Comment: @AlexMarchant as Lex Li pointed out it is fully resolved by using Mac APIs that are available. It is strange that you expect Windows APIs to work on Mac. It would be Windows then.